# Correct Typescript typing for web3 ethereum contract

Tags: web3js, typescript

I'm trying to understand the correct typing I should use for a web3 eth contract that is one of the parameters of my function:

```
import * as express from "express";
import { check, oneOf, validationResult } from "express-validator";
import * as web3 from "web3";

function publicApi(
  app: express.Application,
  blockPartiesPublic: <not sure what should go here>
) {
```

Comment: You can use [TypeChain](https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain) to automatically generate TypeScript bindings for your contracts. See my [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) for a boilerplate that comes with TypeChain pre-configured.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't know for sure if you only want to know the `web3.eth.Contract` type. But if it's what I imagine you can use this:

```
import { Contract } from 'web3-eth-contract';
```

For example:

```
import { Contract } from 'web3-eth-contract';
import { AbiItem } from 'web3-utils';

const TokenInstance: Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi as AbiItem, address)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stay with `web3js` solution only, then using `web3.eth.Contract`, as mentioned by @n3n3, is the correct way. I want to show another option by consuming eth contracts with [github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb). It will generate TypeScript Classes for you with all `read` and `write` methods. You can install them as normal modules.

```sh
$ npm i 0xweb -g
$ 0xweb init

$ 0xweb install ./path/to/abi/BlockPartiesPublic.json --name BlockPartiesPublic --chain eth
```

```
import * as express from "express";
import { check, oneOf, validationResult } from "express-validator";
import { BlockPartiesPublic } from '@0xweb/eth/BlockPartiesPublic/BlockPartiesPublic'

function publicApi(
  app: express.Application,
  blockPartiesPublic: BlockPartiesPublic
) {
}
```

For validated contracts, you can also install classes directly from Etherscan and Co by specifying the address.